# How to upload files to sharepoint site's document library using Graph API on android

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm working on an android app (Java Android) that needs to upload excel files to sharepoint site's library, to begin i took this sample using the graph API : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/android-java-connect-sample
This sample upload a picture to the user's One Drive repository.

So, Thanks to graph explorer, I changed the query so the picture goes to my site's library and it works, but when i execute the query from my android application i get this error :[403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HSHt.png)

My code :

```
public void uploadPictureToOneDrive(byte[] picture, ICallback<DriveItem> callback) {

    try {
        String id = new String("groupeeiffage.sharepoint.com,1f99a971-b596-4c9b-ba31-784d70c05f49,88ea0abd-a92d-412c-b047-86744a64c0ea");
        mGraphServiceClient
                .getSites(id)
                .getDrive()
                .getRoot()
                .getItemWithPath("me.png")
                .getContent()
                .buildRequest()
                .put(picture, callback);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        showException(ex, "exception on upload picture to OneDrive ","Upload picture failed", "The upload picture  method failed");
    }
}
```

I know that's it's an authorization problem but i'm getting lost in the microsoft documentation. How can I allow my app using Graph API to upload files to sharepoint ?

If someone already did something similar i'd really like some help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is missing some key detail such as the code you're using that results in the error, the code you're using to obtain the token, etc.

Comment: Sorry, it's true that my first question was missing a lot of informations, it should be better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, we can use SharePoint REST API to upload a file in Android.

1. Get the security token from Microsoft authentication portal:

```java
public String receiveSecurityToken() throws TransformerException, URISyntaxException {

    RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = 
        new RequestEntity<>(buildSecurityTokenRequestEnvelope(), 
        HttpMethod.POST, 
        new URI("https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf"));

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(new StringSource(responseEntity.getBody()), result);

    Document definitionDocument = (Document) result.getNode();
    String securityToken = xPathExpression.evaluateAsString(definitionDocument);

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(securityToken)) { 
        throw new SharePointAuthenticationException("Unable to authenticate: empty token");
    }

    return securityToken;
}
```

The envelope that is sent to the portal has the following format:

```xml
<s:Envelope 
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" 
            xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:UsernameToken>
                <o:Username>[username]</o:Username>
                <o:Password>[password]</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <t:RequestSecurityToken 
            xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <wsp:AppliesTo 
                xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                <a:EndpointReference>
                    <a:Address>[SharePoint domain address]</a:Address>
                </a:EndpointReference>
            </wsp:AppliesTo>
            <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
            <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
            <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
        </t:RequestSecurityToken>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

2. Get the cookies from the SharePoint Online server:

```java
public List<String> getSignInCookies(String securityToken) throws TransformerException, URISyntaxException {

    RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = 
        new RequestEntity<>(securityToken, 
            HttpMethod.POST, 
            new URI("[SharePoint domain address]/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0"));

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
    HttpHeaders headers = responseEntity.getHeaders();
    List<String> cookies = headers.get("Set-Cookie");

    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cookies)) {
        throw new SharePointSignInException("Unable to sign in: no cookies returned in response");
    } 

    return cookies;
}
```

3. Get the signature(FormDigestValue) for requests to the SharePoint Online server:

```java
public String getFormDigestValue(List<String> cookies) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, 
    TransformerException, JSONException {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("Cookie", Joiner.on(';').join(cookies));
    headers.add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    headers.add("X-ClientService-ClientTag", "SDK-JAVA");

    RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(headers, 
        HttpMethod.POST, new URI("[SharePoint domain address]/_api/contextinfo"));

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseEntity.getBody());

    return json.getJSONObject("d")
        .getJSONObject("GetContextWebInformation").getString("FormDigestValue"); 
}
```

Finally, we can call REST API to upload the document as below.

```http
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)
method: POST
body: "Contents of file"
Headers: Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
         X-RequestDigest: form digest value
         content-length:length of post body
```

```java
public String performHttpRequest(String path, String json, boolean isUpdate) throws Exception {

    String securityToken = receiveSecurityToken();
    List<String> cookies = getSignInCookies(securityToken);
    String formDigestValue = getFormDigestValue(cookies);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("Cookie", Joiner.on(';').join(cookies));
    headers.add("Content-type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    headers.add("X-RequestDigest", formDigestValue);                     

    RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(json, 
        headers, HttpMethod.POST, new URI(path));

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = 
        restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

More information for your reference:

- [SharePoint Online remote authentication (and Doc upload)](http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/)
- [Working with folders and files with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do I need to register my app in Azure to do this ? i started to do some POST request following your link (paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest) and i'm getting a "Direct login to WLID is not allowed for this federated namespace" error when i send it. And it the receiveSecurityToken() class, where do I put my username and password ?

Comment: You don't need to register in Azure, we can do this anthentication with PostMan or Fiddler, so we just need to call the API in Java code step by step as the article shows

Comment: @LeeLiu where we have to pass this xml envelope ?

Comment: @Anurag_BEHS request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf with post method

Comment: is there a dart/flutter package, or code sample, to read and write binary files from mobile device to a sharepoint server?